# How to check address a page is accessed from?

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to grab the URL from which a page is accessed? For example say if I have a file index.php. It can be accessed from virtually anywhere, depending on where I placed it. For example:

```
 - http://folder1/index.php
 - http://nicefolder1/index.php
```

Is there anyway I can find out where the page was accessed from? I'd like to perhaps parse that URL and if it was from nicefolder1, I'd like to do something like `echo "That was a good location to be executed from"` :D! Just something I was curious about ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Should have the url you want.

[More Info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) reference on php.net, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but here's my take on this:

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` holds the host name, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` the absolute path to the requested resource. These two, combined with a scheme prefix, gives you the complete URL:

```
$url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```